# tomcat app using virtual host not accessible outside local network

Tags: networking, tomcat, virtual-host

I use tomcat v8.5 on Windows Server 2019 to deploy my application using a virtual host.
In server.xml:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               />
...
<Host name="name1.name2.example.com"    appBase="webapps/ROOT"/>
```

I am able to access my app deployed in ROOT through the URL `name1.name2.example.com` only from my local network and not from outside the network.

How to make it accessible from outside the network
to note firewall is disabled and port 80 inbound and outbound rules are defined in both ends.

PS: if I change `port="80"` to `port="8080"` the app is accessible from outside the network but using the port number after the FQDN : `name1.name2.example.com:8080` which I don't want (I want to hide the port number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nginx as a reverse proxy can help you get around this issue. You can run your application on any port (e.g., 8080) and use Nginx to forward traffic from port 80 to that port. This way, external users won't need to specify a port number when accessing your application.

Comment: this for windows server 19?

Comment: Yes, alternative is also apache server- supports reverse proxy as well- if you choose apache server you can add something like this to config: 

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:1234/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1234/
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: port 1234 is open for tomcat?

Comment: This was just example, replace 1234 with 8080 :)